# Initializing object from static variable Objective C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, initialization

Hello I am currently translating a project that was written in Objective C into swift and I am running into a puzzle. In objective C the Object (SearchItem) is a sub class of object Item and has a static variable of the same class (SearchItem). The static variable is initialized in a static function. The problem is on objective C there is a non-static function that initializes the super class variables, I tried to replicate this but I am not 100% how to approach this, I would like to keep the same format if possible, any help would be great!

Obj C:

.h file includes:

```
 @interface SearchItem : Item
```

.m file includes:

```
static SearchItem *sharedSearchItem = nil;

+(id)sharedSearchItem {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(sharedSearchItem == nil){
            sharedSearchItem = [SearchItem new];
            //other methods
        }
    }
    return sharedSearchItem;
}
-(void)configureWithSettingsConfig:(SettingsConfig *)settings{
    NSLog(@"%@", [super initWithSettings:settings]);
    //Other methods 
}
```

Swift:

```
static var sharedSearchItem: SearchItem? = nil

static func sharedSearchItemInit(){
        if(sharedSearchItem == nil){
            sharedSearchItem = SearchItem()
            //Other methods
        }
    }

    func configureWithSettingsConfig(settings: SettingsConfig){
        print(SearchItem.init(settings: settings)) // creates separate object need it to be on same instantiation
        /*
        The following calls won’t work
        self = ServiceFacade.init(settings: settings)
        self.init(settings: settings)
        super.init(settings: settings)*/
        //Other methods

    }
```

Comment: `+(id)sharedSearchItem` is a class method, not a static function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift the way we create Singletons is simply like so:

```
static let sharedSearchItem = SearchItem()
```

That's it.  No need for a special "sharedInit" function.

Comment: Thank you for your response! thats great to know, but what If I want to initialize later on the variables that are in the super class, the SearchItem() will instantiate everything but If I want to initialize with a specific setting as in the configure function shows?

Comment: Why not just make those variables mutable, and run your `configure` function whenever you need to set those properties.  You'd just need to call `SearchItem.sharedSearchItem.configureWithSettings(...`